# Is it possible to display multiple levels with Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After loading the `Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension` we can select a floor with:

`levelsExt.floorSelector.selectFloor(1, true)`

My question is, is there a way to select multiple floors? For example 1st floor and 3rd floor, or does the extension only allow 1 floor selection at a time.

For completeness, the extension is loaded with:
`levelsExt = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension')`
and the viewer refers to the Autodesk Forge Viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension only allows one floor at a time since it uses cut planes to 'select' objects. If you want to show 2 adjacent floors, I think it is possible by moving one of the cut plan from example roof floor 1 to roof floor 2, keeping ground floor 1 where it is - therefore you would have floor 1 and 2. But it would not be possible to get floor 1 and floor 5, unless you write your own extension to do multiple cut plane selection. Below is an example of doing 2 adjacent floors selection.

```js
// Select floor 2
const CutPlaneSetName = 'Autodesk.AEC.FloorSelector';
let floorIndex = 2;
floorExtension.floorSelector.selectFloor(floorIndex);

// Capture roof floor 2 
const cuts2 = myviewer.impl.getCutPlaneSet(CutPlaneSetName);

// Select floor 1
floorIndex = 1;
floorExtension.floorSelector.selectFloor(floorIndex);

// Capture roof floor 1 
const cuts1 = myviewer.impl.getCutPlaneSet(CutPlaneSetName);

// Restore roof floor 2
const planes = [ cuts1[0], cuts2[1] ];
myviewer.impl.setCutPlaneSet(CutPlaneSetName, planes);
```